# OpenID architectural pattern advice

Tags: angular, openid, wso2-api-manager, openid-connect, wso2-identity-server

I open this thread because I need both theoretical and practical support (I must say that I am quite ignorant) about authentication and authorization processes for web applications.

I developed a simple web application using Angular6 for the frontend and Java for creating the REST services that interact with the frontend.
In detail the frontend is exposed through Apache2 Web Server and the webapp is deployed in Tomcat8 (exposed with the reverse proxy).
Having said that I would like to insert into architecture:
a token-based authentication and authorization process
an API Manager system for managing the Rest APIs and related tokens

Searching on Google I understood that OpenID is the right protocol and the basic architecture that I should set is the one described here (https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/api-management/identity-propagation-in-an-api-gateway-architecture).

Studying all the available open-source technologies, I identified WSO2 providing both an API Manager and an Identity Server.
I would like to have support from the community both to understand what the correct architectural and communication pattern is and if there is a guide to do this with Apache2 + WSO2 products + Tomcat.
Thanks in advance to everyone.

Comment: @d_f thanks a lot. I've just updated tag's list.

Answer (score 1):

At a high level there are 3 moving parts:
" Web UI redirects and gets a token
* API receives a token and validates it
* Authorization Server manages logins + issuing of tokens

My tutorial + code sample may help you understand whether this works for you:
https://authguidance.com/2017/09/24/basicspa-overview/

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested in putting the web app and/or API behind an OpenID Connect Relying Party (or OAuth 2.0 Resource Server) module plugged into the Apache reverse proxy, [mod_auth_openidc](https://github.com/zmartzone/mod_auth_openidc) which can consume the tokens issued by the WSO2 server.